# SVN repository section doesn't show in team in eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have installed Tortoise SVN and the subsclipse plugin to Eclipse as well. So when I right click the project, I should be able to go to the team and commit via SVN.\

But when I right click the project and go to the team, it only shows apply project and share project. It doesn't show SVN. I tried most of the solutions which has mentioned in forums. But couldn't find a solution. Please tell me a solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: If Eclipse does not think the project is shared that is all you get, the SVN options appear once the project is 'shared' on SVN.

Comment: But all the other guys don't share it. But they can access the SVN options.

Comment: Did they check it out from SVN (using Eclipse)? That will cause Eclipse to treat it as shared

Comment: Everyone is checking out from SVN including me. But to them it shows the SVN options. Not to me.